# How to recursively remove CSS classes

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to recursively remove all CSS classes from DIVs using jQuery.

this is what I've got so far, but it simply does not work

http://jsfiddle.net/qxy7yotj/4/ (**UPDATED**)

//**UPDATE**: another problem is that I have HTML as a JAvascript String and I have to manipulate with it this way

HTML:

```
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c3">some text
      <div>blah blah</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('div').removeClass();

$('div').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).removeClass();
});
```

Comment: You just need to add jQuery to your fiddle and the syntax `$('div').removeClass();` is just fine...

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/qxy7yotj/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an element on the fly, then search inside it:

```
var s = '<div class="c1"> <div class="c1"><div class="c3">some text<div>blah blah</div></div></div></div>'

var $elem =
    // create on the fly element
    $('<div></div>')

        // put your string to its content
        .html(s)

        // find `div` elements
        .find('div')

            // remove `class` attribute
            .removeAttr('class');

$('#id').html($elem.html());
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qxy7yotj/7/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [**jQuery to your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/qxy7yotj/3/), as this is the syntax you are writing your Javascript in.

Then you simply need to use:

```
$('div').removeAttr('class');
```

Comment: @Igor...your update kind of changes the nature of the question!

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeAttr('class')` and load jQuery in your Fiddle
check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/qxy7yotj/2/)

```
$('div').each(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('class');
});
```